# How to figure out what port my application is using from inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ofx

I am trying to write a program that will interface with my bank using OFX4J (Java implementation of OFX). Since I am getting an error, I want to see what exactly I am sending them that is generating the error. I downloaded the Eclipse Web Tools zip, installed it, and opened the TCP/IP monitor, but when I run the program it doesn't pick up anything. I assume this is because it isn't listening to the right port.

How do I see what port my application is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Linux / MacOS, you can do it from terminal: `netstat -vatp tcp | grep LISTEN`. If you want to actually figure out some ports - just put out breakpoint into a constructor of `java.net.Socket#Socket(java.lang.String, int)` or `java.net.ServerSocket#ServerSocket(int, int, java.net.InetAddress)` and start up the application again in debug mode.